# On startup, highlight tags and display tags in a preview window

Tags: vim

I am using Vim as a note-taking and outlining tool. I am constructing the "tags" file by myself. What I would like to do is that when I open my notes or
outline file, Vim reads the tags present in this file, highlights them and also displays the tag labels in a vertical preview window. I have no experience
in Vim scripting so I would appreciate some help.

Currently I am using a `bash` script to generate a tag labels file "taglabels" in `$PWD` using `cut` and loading it in a separate vertical window.

My script looks like this

```
#! /bin/bash

cut -f1 $PWD/tags > $PWD/taglabels
vi -c ":30vsp $PWD/taglabels" $1
```

As is obvious, the script does not highlight the tags present in the file nor does it it show only the tags present in the file. On the contrary it shows
all the tags present in `$PWD/tags`.

I looked into `ctags` and the `taglist` plugin but they seem to be more suited for code than for free form text.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using vim and the outline facilities a plugin provides?

Comment: @Sardathrion -- I have been trying to look for such a plugin for some time now!! I took a look at [taglist.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/taglist.vim) but it seems to need exuberant ctags which suggests to me that it would not be suitable for my purpose, since I am tagging free-form text. I did try to use it anyways but it did not work (it only opened the side pane with an error message and no tags from the tags file in the current working directory).

Comment: Ah, sorry it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If your tags file is in proper tags database format (like generated by *ctags*), there are some plugins that offer tag highlighting:

- [TagHighlight](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2646)
- [EasyTags](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114)

However, both assume tags generation by *ctags*. Maybe you can turn off that part or extract the highlighting part.